# Connect local frontend with smart contract on ropsten

Tags: truffle, ropsten, frontend

I'm new to DApp programming an I'm struggling with this problem since two days now.

Cloned this github example: https://github.com/dappuniversity/election
I deployed the smart contract to ropsten with remix.ethereum. The deployment works and I can interact with it in remix.
Now I want to interact with my local frontend with the smart contract on the testnet.
I can not get this to work.

I'm using the exact same frontend from the repo. In the chrome console I get the message "Error: Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)"

I changed the contract address in the Election.json and in the Migration.json to the new correct one which I had deployed. Also copyd the abi from remix.ethereum and replaced it in Election.json and Migration.json

MetaMask is on the correct network.

What did I miss out? Do I need to rebuild something with truffle or change the network in truffle.js?
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Did you add the deployed contract addresses under ropsten network id? ropsten network id is 3, truffle testnet is 5777.

Comment: this worked thank you. if you post it as answer i accept it

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to edit json artifacts to add a new section with ropsten network id (= 3) in "networks"

```
  "networks": {
    "5777": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "0x30753e4a8aad7f8597332e813735def5dd395028"
    },
    "3": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "<ROPSTEN_ADDRESS>"
    }
  },
```